# connect with C# console application to internal DB of asp.net mvc 4 website

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-4

is there any chance to connect into default DB of asp.net mvc 4 application?

I have one running website on server, and another C# console application, also on same server. And I'm trying to figure how to put some queries (insert/update) from that console app to database created in asp.net application. Of course website app is running.

Any ideas?

//edit

I need this cause of creating web application for "imports" (it's bigger amount of data, about 300k records from Excel file). And I don't want push user to have opened website whole time while updating database ("backside processing"). If you have some another idea how to make it, I will be really happy to hear it

Answer (score 1):

Default MVC 4 app uses SQLEXPRESS server, so you can just copy connection string from MVC app to your console app and it will work.

The only possible problem that user who runs console application, does not have rights to access DB

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the same connection string.

If you are using Windows Authentication, you will need to add the user that will be logged into the server to the SQL Server logins and grant datareader and datawriter permissions on the database for that user.

If you are using SQL Authentication the username/password should be in the connection string and that user should already have permissions.

Comment: to be honest. I'm not pretty sure about authentication which exactly I'm using. It should be `Integrated Security=True`? Whole connection string seems like this `Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Magicc.mdf;Integrated Security=True`